# How can I hide or ignore old Outlook iCal invitations?

Tags: ical, exchange

I often ignore invitations to office events on my phone, and then answer them later from iCal on my Macbook. Sometimes there are old invitations for events that have already occurred. However, the only options in iCal are `Maybe`, `Decline` or `Accept`.

If I choose any of these an email is sent to the requester which is confusing for them. How do I remove these from my queue without triggering an email? In other words, where is the `Remove` or `Hide` button?

Update 2013-01-08: The problem is that the invitations no longer appear on my phone (the "Invitations" list is empty) however they still appear in my Mac's iCal tray.

[image: Would an "Ignore" button be so hard?]

Comment: Have you tried swiping (left to right or right to left) on the event in the table view to see if a Delete button comes up? I don't have any invitations to try it with.

Comment: Unfortunately the old invitations appear only on the Mac and not on the phone at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that several similar forum threads have your question and have had no success in finding an option in iCal to Ignore or Remove an invitation without clicking one of the options you have listed, which sends an email. Here is a workaround that is worth a try if you don't want iCal to trigger an email:

Use [iCal Reply Checker](http://www.nhoj.co.uk/icalreplychecker/). I've tried it myself and it works great to prevent or change the emails iCal sends when responding to an invitation.  It is shareware, however, so remove all of the old events you need within the ten days that the application is free.

Answer (score 6):

For an Exchange account the only way I found to clear old invites out was to log into Outlook Web Access in my web browser and decline them without sending an email in there. Just go to the same dates specified in iCal for the invites and use the right click menu in the calendar tab to decline them.

Answer (score 5):

actually for me it worked to delete the caches: http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=12386508

Comment: This worked for me too. Deleting the caches cleared the notification for events that have already taken place.

Comment: These instructions also worked for me, but I had to re-enable calendars for each account in the Calendar > Accounts menu on OS X 10.9.x.

Comment: The content on the http://kb.mit.edu site requires a login. Can someone copy the content here?

Answer (score 1):

On the webpage for Ical Reply Checker it says:
Note: iCal Reply Checker is not compatible with notifications sent by iCal using Exchange or CalDAV servers including the iCloud calendar.

Unfortunately I have this issue with an Exchange account (as probably most ppl will)...

Answer (score 1):

Disable the internet connection on your mac. Then click any of the invitation replies. Go to the Mail application and delete the message from the outbox. Restore internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

All I did to get rid of the previous invitations on my iPad was to remove the exchange account from the iPad all together and then re-add the account again. This may not work for a few though because for some reason you may want to view to previous events on your iPad and it looks like it eats rid of all the previous events. However it worked for me how I wanted it to and there are no more invitations that I can't get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy actually. Go to the day of the notification. Highlight it on your calendar. Then select "Delete without Notifying"

Comment: Are you sure this works with Outlook calendars and Mac iCal? I try to delete the event and it pops up with a "Decline event" dialog - no "Delete without Notifying" option in sight...

Comment: I did what Nuri suggested and it worked. Too bad there is no menu option for deleting old invitations without having to go to the month page for each event.

Comment: The only option is Delete, which the user is then prompted with a Decline or Cancel option. THere is no "Delete without Notifying" in Calendar on OS X 10.8.4 with an Exchange calendar.

Comment: This approach does work with Yosemite Calendar against an Exchange server (hosted Office 365 at least). Just find the item in Calendar (it will probably be colored grey), select it and press Delete. You will be given the option to "Delete without Notifying"

Answer (score 0):

Success!   In the iCalendar menu, click View==>Show Declined Events.  Once they appear, right-click on one and choose whether to Delete that instance or Delete All occurrences.